# Connecting to Ingres and Oracle from C

Tags: c, unix, oracle11g, ingres

My client given code is programmed in c language to connect to Ingres Database in Unix environment.
This code is using API's such DBconnect(), DBExecSQL,DBRollback()....

I want to confirm that whether these API's are Ingres database specific API's?

Can I use these API's for connecting to Oracle DB.

If I cannot use those same API's to connect to Oracle DB, how to connect to Oracle Database from c program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm they're not Ingres-specific API calls, which are things like IIapi_connect().

It's possible they're part of some 3rd party interface layer for which there's also an Oracle driver. Or they could be something they have written themselves and are in a library somewhere.